# mousewheel.min.js is not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I am using a simple horizontal scrolling setup on my page.  Its for showcasing photographs.  The below codes are what corresponds to the setup.  It works beautifully and smoothly in Chrome, so far it will not scroll with the mousewheel in IE

In Head of Html Document:

```
$(function() {
        $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

The jQuery script is the latest version 3.1.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think JQuery have version 3.x... Consider adding version of IE and location of script your are talking about to the post.

Comment: I've never heard of version 3... Use jquery [1.10.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js)

Comment: Sorry about that guys.   my two files are:  jquery-1.10.2.min.js and jquery.mousewheel.min  (the mousewheel version was 3.1.6 as per the download site)